# SelectBox in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a little bit new to Google Script so apologies if my question is silly. I have the following user scenario:
- on a monthly basis I get standard file from on of my departments
- I save the file on Google Drive and automatically copy certain information to my Sheets that I use to analyse this information
- I finished the code that does the copy, selection, etc.

I am struggling with the first piece - some sort of SelectBox that I would use to select source file. I can write code that will search Google Drive and display potential files, display them in ListBox, but maybe there is other way (the simpler the better). What would you recommend here?

Google has nice Box that shows up when you try to copy sheet into other Sheets document, but it seems not to be avaialble for Script.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I’d make the source selection with JavaScript on a client side dialog and load content with google.script.run and success handler on document.ready.

Comment: Regarding the "nice box" see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

Comment: Ruben, this is so cool! Thanks a lot. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, I have 3 questions regarding Picker example. Would be great if you could help me with those:
1) How to get rid of "Select a file button" that shows up at the very outset? I need it press it first before piker loads.
2) How to close windo once I select file? So far this stays untill I manually close it (x button in top right corner).
3) Finally, how to run certain function once I select the file. I need to pass there id of a file (which is easy to get), but so far did not manage to execute other function - like myFunction();

Any help is much appreciated.